# How to Send image using org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext for email

Tags: spring, image, email, velocity, email-attachments

```
MimeMessagePreparator mimeMessagePreparator=new MimeMessagePreparator() {

@Override
public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper=new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setTo(requestQuotationPojo.getEmailId().toString());
                    mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("vikasglobaljapan@gmail.com");
                    mimeMessageHelper.setText("Your Request Quotation Number"+requestQuotationPojo.getRfqId());
                    mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("Request Quotation Details");
    VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();

    requestQuotationPojo.setImage(new StringBuffer(application_url.concat(requestQuotationPojo.getImage().toString())));
    requestQuotationPojo.setRfqId(new StringBuffer(rfqId));

    velocityContext.put("image", requestQuotationPojo.getImage());
    velocityContext.put("rfqDetails", requestQuotationPojo);
                    velocityContext.put("image",application_url.concat(requestQuotationPojo.getImage().toString()));

   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
   velocityEngine.mergeTemplate("com/gjcp/dao/daoImpl/customer/templateName.vm", "UTF-8", velocityContext, stringWriter);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setText(stringWriter.toString(), true);
                }
```

template.vm

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlusÂ®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table style="width:100%">
Â  <tr>
Â Â Â  <th>Product Name</th>
Â Â Â  <th>Quote Number</th>
Â Â Â  <th>Image</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
Â  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>${rfqDetails.productName}</td>
    <td> ${rfqDetails.rfqId}</td>
    <td><img src="${rfqDetails.image}" border="0" width="50" height="50"></td>
    <td>${rfqDetails.quantity}</td>
  </tr>

</table>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I suppose that your image is a byte array. So you should add image to velocity context as base64 string.

  `velocityContext.put("image", Base64.encode(requestQuotationPojo.getImage()));`
- And use this img tag in your template file.

  `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${image}" border="0" width="50" height="50"/>`

Comment: In my database storing the image path url. while sending the email img src <img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Edf_2yhejOyVjXb4iU30GSzEGQlhC2PcnalRq2rW27EBI1qo3VV1aLR8s_vVCmDIXrT8LCLbJmxSY47cbX-c9CxxmY3VeK2zDUPh0F2E7LELU-aSEAMCYkQlJP0MTHliFCGxUnfBHmunCRRw0nEk2sOKHVFEMqA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://192.168.1.17:8080/project//myresources/projectfiles/projectimages/241120161447478.jpg" class="CToWUd" height="50" width="50" border="0">

Comment: i am getting the image url from the database. while sending email the gmail path included with my image path like <img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Edf_2yhejOyVjXb4iU30GSzEGQlhC2PcnalRq2rW27EBI1qo3VV1aLR8s_vVCmDIXrT8LCLbJmxSY47cbX-c9CxxmY3VeK2zDUPh0F2E7LELU-aSEAMCYkQlJP0MTHliFCGxUnfBHmunCRRw0nEk2sOKHVFEMqA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://192.168.1.17:8080/project//myresources/projectfiles/projectimages/241120161447478.jpg" class="CToWUd" height="50" width="50" border="0">

Answer (score 1):

${websitename} : Write Your website name.

${rfqDetails.image} : your image path.

> Like Your image url: http://test.com/folder/abc.png

```
#set($imgsrc="http://${websitename}/${rfqDetails.image})

 <img width="50" src="$imgsrc" border="0" height="50" alt="test">
```